# How to select multiple records from SQL and insert into a Session

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, multiple-select

I am looking for how to insert multiple records from a SQL table into a session variable, or into multiple unique session variables.

```
$userID = $_SESSION['user']['id']; 

$coursequery = " 
            SELECT
                coursename,
                location,
                description 
            FROM courses 
            WHERE 
                teacherID = '$userID' 
        "; 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($coursequery); 
            $result = $stmt->execute(); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

            $_SESSION['courseinfo'] = $row;
```

The table "courses" has a few records inside, all with the teacherID being that of the current userID, defined at the start. When I print_r($_SESSION['courseinfo']); it only displays one of the records in the table.

I'm trying to create a loop that displays all the information grabbed, for each record, since you won't know for sure how many records you'll grab at any given time. Any answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use fetchAll() which would return an array with all your rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all your records with changing the fetch -> fetchAll() [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Sessions can also store arrays and objects (they get serialized automatically). So you can just store the whole results set there.

```
$_SESSION['courseinfo'] = $rows;
```

Side note: Consider using another storage place for all of the returned data, if its a lot, and in the session store only Ids.

Answer (score 2):

```
$userID = $_SESSION['user']['id']; 

$coursequery = " 
            SELECT
                coursename,
                location,
                description 
            FROM courses 
            WHERE 
                teacherID = '$userID' 
        "; 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($coursequery); 
            $result = $stmt->execute(); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()):

         $row['YourColumn'];

         endwhile;
```

Use while() loop to fetch all record as per your query